# Use the google navigation card in my dialogflow agent

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Is there a way i can use Google's Navigation Card, the one shown when you ask something like "Navigate to home", in my agent ?  I can't find any tutorials related to this.
I was trying to open Maps application, but this (Google's Navigation Card) is more suitable to my requirement, as if the user doesn't want to go to the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actions on Google (the Google Assistnat 3rd party platform) doesn't support navigation cards for 3rd party apps yet.  You can emulate a navigation card by:

1. Creating a [basic card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card)
2. Make the image of the basic card a screenshot of the directions
3. Make the button of the basic card a [deep link to Google maps for the desired directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#forming-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

No, the Actions on Google platform is separate from whatever capabilities are on the underlying OS platform.

You may wish to look into using the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) to provide the image and path as an overview on a card, and then include a link out to the app if the user wants to do navigation.

Comment: But is Google's Navigation Card related to underlying system ?
I thought this was another card like link account card.